# Sudoku Solving Function Explanation

Tags: c++, sudoku, solver

I have been searching for a Sudoku Solving Algorithm for a while and I found this code. But I have some difficulties. I can't understand it. If there are conflicts with all numbers between 1 and 9 in a single cell, the program should stop, right? But it continues. Can somebody explain me how the code works, please? Here it is:

```
bool Sudoku::Help_Solve(int i, int j)
{
    int nextrow, nextcol;
    while(change[i][j] == 1) //We find the first cell in which we can change the number
    {                      
        j++;
        if(j > 9)
        {
            j = 1;
            i++;     
        }     
        if(i > 9) return true;            
    }


    for(int p = 1; p <= 9; p++)
    {
        if(Game.Check_Conflicts(p, i, j)) //We are checking for conflicts
        {
            board[i][j] = p;
            nextrow = i;
            nextcol = j+1;    
            if(nextcol > 9)
            {
                nextcol = 1;
                nextrow++;     
            } 
            if(nextcol == 1 && nextrow == 10) return true; 
            if(Game.Help_Solve(nextrow, nextcol)) return true;                   
        }      
    }
    board[i][j] = 0;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What do mean by *conflicts with all numbers between 1 and 9 in a single cell*?

Comment: I mean that none of the numbers between 1-9 fit in this cell. Shouldn't it go backwards?

Comment: Don't expect this algorithm to be anywhere near efficient.

Comment: The thing is rhat I can't understand why it continues if in the end it returns false :/

Answer (score 0):

Not enough code to explain properly, what happens in Game.Check_Conflicts(p, i, j), is this function getting called recursively?

Comment: No. It checks if 'p' occurs in the small 3x3 box where is the cell in which we try to insert a number and if 'p' occurs in the same roll or column.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the whole code if you want to see it:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Sudoku
  {
    private:
    int board[9][9];
    int change[9][9];
    public:
    Sudoku();
    void Print_Board();  
    void Add_First_Cord();  
    bool Help_Solve(int i, int j);
    bool Check_Conflicts(int p, int i, int j);
  };

Sudoku Game;  

void setcolor(unsigned short color)                 //The function that you'll use to
{                                                   //set the colour
    HANDLE hcon = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hcon,color);
}

Sudoku::Sudoku()
  {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
      for(int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        board[i][j] = 0;            
  }

void Sudoku::Print_Board()
  {
    for(int i = 1; i <= 9; i++)
      {
        for(int j = 1; j <= 9; j++)
          {
            if(change[i][j] == 1) 
              {
                setcolor(12);
                cout << board[i][j] << " ";
                setcolor(7);           
              }
              else cout << board[i][j] << " ";  
              if(j%3 == 0) cout << "| ";
          }
        cout << endl;
        if(i%3 == 0) cout << "------+-------+--------" << endl;

      }                    
  }

void Sudoku::Add_First_Cord()
  {
    board[1][1] = 5; change[1][1] = 1;
    board[1][2] = 3; change[1][2] = 1;     
    board[1][5] = 7; change[1][5] = 1;      
    board[2][1] = 6; change[2][1] = 1;  
    board[2][4] = 1; change[2][4] = 1;       
    board[2][5] = 9; change[2][5] = 1;  
    board[2][6] = 5; change[2][6] = 1;
    board[3][2] = 9; change[3][2] = 1;      
    board[3][3] = 8; change[3][3] = 1;   
    board[3][8] = 6; change[3][8] = 1;     
    board[4][1] = 8; change[4][1] = 1;    
    board[4][5] = 6; change[4][5] = 1;    
    board[4][9] = 3; change[4][9] = 1;    
    board[5][1] = 4; change[5][1] = 1;
    board[5][4] = 8; change[5][4] = 1;  
    board[5][6] = 3; change[5][6] = 1;  
    board[5][9] = 1; change[5][9] = 1;   
    board[6][1] = 7; change[6][1] = 1;
    board[6][5] = 2; change[6][5] = 1;   
    board[6][9] = 6; change[6][9] = 1;  
    board[7][2] = 6; change[7][2] = 1;  
    board[7][7] = 2; change[7][7] = 1;  
    board[7][8] = 8; change[7][8] = 1;  
    board[8][4] = 4; change[8][4] = 1;
    board[8][5] = 1; change[8][5] = 1;   
    board[8][6] = 9; change[8][6] = 1;
    board[8][9] = 5; change[8][9] = 1;   
    board[9][5] = 8; change[9][5] = 1;  
    board[9][8] = 7; change[9][8] = 1;  
    board[9][9] = 9; change[9][9] = 1; 
  }

bool Sudoku::Check_Conflicts(int p, int i, int j)
  {
    for(int k = 1; k <= 9; k++)
      if(board[i][k] == p) return false;

    for(int q = 1; q <= 9; q++)
      if(board[q][j] == p) return false;

    /*
      *00
      000
      000
    */
    if((j == 1 || j == 4 || j == 7) && (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7))
      {
         if(board[i][j+1] == p || board[i][j+2] == p || board[i+1][j] == p || 
             board[i+2][j] == p || board[i+1][j+1] == p || board[i+1][j+2] == p || 
                 board[i+2][j+1] == p || board[i+2][j+2] == p)return false;     
      } 

    /*
      000
      000
      *00
    */  
    if((j == 1 || j == 4 || j == 7) && (i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9))
      {
         if(board[i-1][j] == p || board[i-2][j] == p || board[i][j+1] == p || 
             board[i][j+2] == p || board[i-1][j+1] == p || board[i-1][j+2] == p || 
                 board[i-2][j+1] == p || board[i-2][j+2] == p)return false;   
      }

    /*
      000
      *00
      000
    */            
    if((j == 1 || j == 4 || j == 7) && (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8))
      {
         if(board[i-1][j] == p || board[i-1][j+1] == p || board[i-1][j+2] == p || 
             board[i][j+1] == p || board[i][j+2] == p || board[i+1][j] == p || 
                 board[i+1][j+1] == p || board[i+1][j+2] == p)return false;  
      } 


    /*
      0*0
      000
      000
    */            
    if((j == 2 || j == 5 || j == 8) && (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7))
      {
         if(board[i][j-1] == p || board[i][j+1] == p || board[i+1][j+1] == p || 
             board[i+1][j-1] == p || board[i+1][j] == p || board[i+2][j-1] == p || 
                 board[i+2][j] == p || board[i+2][j+1] == p)return false;  
      }

    /*
      000
      0*0
      000
    */            
    if((j == 2 || j == 5 || j == 8) && (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8))
      {
         if(board[i-1][j] == p || board[i-1][j-1] == p || board[i-1][j+1] == p || 
             board[i][j+1] == p || board[i][j-1] == p || board[i+1][j+1] == p || 
                 board[i+1][j] == p || board[i+1][j-1] == p)return false;  
      }


    /*
      000
      000
      0*0
    */            
    if((j == 2 || j == 5 || j == 8) && (i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9))
      {
         if(board[i][j-1] == p || board[i][j+1] == p || board[i-1][j] == p || 
             board[i-1][j+1] == p || board[i-1][j-1] == p || board[i-2][j] == p || 
                 board[i-2][j+1] == p || board[i-2][j-1] == p) return false;  
      }  

    /*
      00*
      000
      000
    */            
    if((j == 3 || j == 6 || j == 9) && (i == 1 || i == 4 || i == 7))
      {
         if(board[i][j-1] == p || board[i][j-2] == p || board[i+1][j] == p || 
             board[i+1][j-1] == p || board[i+1][j-2] == p || board[i+2][j] == p || 
                 board[i+2][j-1] == p || board[i+2][j-2] == p) return false;  
      } 

    /*
      000
      00*
      000
    */            
    if((j == 3 || j == 6 || j == 9) && (i == 2 || i == 5 || i == 8))
      {
         if(board[i-1][j] == p || board[i-1][j-1] == p || board[i-1][j-2] == p || 
             board[i][j-1] == p || board[i][j-2] == p || board[i+1][j] == p || 
                 board[i+1][j-1] == p || board[i+1][j-2] == p) return false;  
      }

    /*
      000
      000
      00*
    */            
    if((j == 3 || j == 6 || j == 9) && (i == 3 || i == 6 || i == 9))
      {
         if(board[i][j-1] == p || board[i][j-2] == p || board[i-1][j] == p || 
             board[i-1][j-1] == p || board[i-1][j-2] == p || board[i-2][j] == p || 
                 board[i-2][j-1] == p || board[i-2][j-2] == p) return false;  
      }      

    return true;                          
  }

bool Sudoku::Help_Solve(int i, int j)
  {
    int nextrow, nextcol;
    while(change[i][j] == 1)
      {
        j++;
        if(j > 9)
          {
            j = 1;
            i++;     
          }     
        if(i > 9) return true;            
      }


    for(int p = 1; p <= 9; p++)
      {
        if(Game.Check_Conflicts(p, i, j))
          {
            board[i][j] = p;
            nextrow = i;
            nextcol = j+1;    
            if(nextcol > 9)
              {
                nextcol = 1;
                nextrow++;     
              } 
            if(nextcol == 1 && nextrow == 10) return true; 
            if(Game.Help_Solve(nextrow, nextcol)) return true;                   
          }      
      }
    board[i][j] = 0;
    return false;

  }


int main()
{
  Game.Add_First_Cord();
  Game.Help_Solve(1, 1);
  Game.Print_Board();  

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `Sudoku::Check_Conflicts` returns `true` if the number CAN be placed there, or `false` if it CAN'T be placed there due to a simple conflict.  A different function name could maybe better self-document the code.

Comment: Yeah it checks if it is possible to place 'p' in this cell and return true if Yes and false if Not.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is rhat I can't understand why it continues if in the end it
>   returns false :/

It doesn't ALWAYS return at the bottom of the function tho':

```
bool Sudoku::Help_Solve(int i, int j)
{
    int nextrow, nextcol;
    while(change[i][j] == 1) //We find the first cell in which we can change the number
    {                      
        j++;
        if(j > 9)
        {
            j = 1;
            i++;     
        }     
        if(i > 9) return true;            

-------------------------^^^^
returns true if we have filled all squares.

    }


    for(int p = 1; p <= 9; p++)
    {
        if(Game.Check_Conflicts(p, i, j)) //We are checking for conflicts
        {
            board[i][j] = p;
            nextrow = i;
            nextcol = j+1;    
            if(nextcol > 9)
            {
                nextcol = 1;
                nextrow++;     
            } 
            if(nextcol == 1 && nextrow == 10) return true; 
-----------------------------------------------------^^^^   
           returns when we have filled everything!

            if(Game.Help_Solve(nextrow, nextcol)) return true;                
---------------------------------------------------------^^^^
          returns if we filled at the next level of solution. 
        }      
    }
    board[i][j] = 0;
    return false;
-----------^^^^^ returns if we failed to fill the whole thing. 
}
```

As someone else mentioned in a comment, there are some trivial things that can be done to improve on the algorithm - such as looking for the "most suitable place to fill first" [which doesn't improve the worst case, but it does improve the typical case].

I have written a Sudoku solver that uses a similar algorithm, but it tries to find the cell with the lowest number of candidates (possible numbers to go in the that cell) and only tries recursively if there are multiple choices.

Comment: but if no suitable number is found, the program goes out of the loop and returns false, right?

Comment: @SinanZikri Yes, because then we've "done something wrong". This is a "try different solutions" solver (and it's a much easier way, in terms of writing than code) to solve the problem than to implement all the different methods that a human would use. Basically "If we put 3 in this box, can we solve the puzzle". If at some point down the line, it turns out that NO digit can be put in a particular place, then you have to stop and go back and change that digit.